# Ошибка I\O error 103 (Delphi XE3)

Tags: delphi, io

Почему выскакивает ошибка при обработке файла: **I\O error 103** ?

```
var
  fall, f1: TextFile;
  S: string;
begin
    AssignFile(fall, OpenDialog1.FileName);
    reset(fall);

    if CheckBox1.Checked then
    begin
        AssignFile(f1, 'Organization.txt');
        rewrite(f1);
    end;

    //работаем по строкам в файле
    while not Eof(fall) do
    begin
        //читаем строку
        ReadLn(fall, S);
        if CheckBox1.Checked and (Pos(AnsiLowerCase(Edit1.Text), AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) then
            writeln(f1, S);
    end;

    CloseFile(fall);
    CloseFile(f1); // <<-- Ошибка выскакивает тут
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if CheckBox1.Checked then
  CloseFile(f1);
```

Comment: Поясните свой ответ?

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка, с большой долей вероятности, случается потому, что файлы вы открываете на чтение/запись по условию, а вот закрываете файл затем уже в любом случае. Скорее всего, одно из условий:

```
if CheckBox1.Checked then
if CheckBox2.Checked then
if CheckBox3.Checked then
```

у вас не выполняется, но при этом `CloseFile` вы делаете для всех файлов без условий. Исправьте это, введя те же самые условия и для `CloseFile`.

Comment: Ошибка именно в этом - легко проверить на вызове `CloseFile(f);` без предварительного открытия файла.

Comment: @Kromster  103 ошибка могла бы быть ещё при попытке записи в уже открытый файл (+ еще несколько ошибок, связанных с записью в файл), поэтому нельзя быть изначально до конца уверенным :)

Comment: В таком случае, конечно, стоило попросить ТС привести "минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример" (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)